# cannot convert data coming from firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, casting

i am retrieving data from child from firebase database, the first child after the reference is "cars" which i reach with mRoot
then i use iterative to reach every child in "cars"
then i get the data into car class
at first i created the class with string values then it said you can't convert long values to string
then i turned it to long and it said you cannot convert string values to long

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.example.ahmed.pointoflife.LogIn$1$1.onDataChange(LogIn.java:55)

## when changing

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to long
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.example.ahmed.pointoflife.LogIn$1$1.onDataChange(LogIn.java:55)

```
mRoot.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Car car = new Car();
                    car.setHospital(childSnapshot.child("hospital").getValue(Long.class));
                    car.setId(childSnapshot.child("id").getValue(Long.class));
                    car.setPassword(childSnapshot.child("password").getValue(Long.class));
                    h.put(car.getId().toString(),car);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


package com.example.ahmed.pointoflife;
import com.google.firebase.database.PropertyName;
public class Car {

    private Long hospital,id,password;
    public Car(Long hospital,Long id,Long passowrd)
    {
     this.hospital = hospital;
     this.id = id;
     this.password = passowrd;

    }
    Car(){

    }

    @PropertyName("hospital")
    public Long getHospital() {
        return hospital;
    }

    public void setHospital(Long hospital) {
        this.hospital = hospital;
    }

    @PropertyName("id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @PropertyName("password")
    public Long getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(Long password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

firebase tree
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17xYkrFwZqscCdrzvfkStr6cC-VYaQHI1/view?usp=sharing

how can i take these values correctly from firebase without troubles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `mRoot` points to the Firebase root, to solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
mRoot.addValueEventListener(*/ ... */);
```

to

```
mRoot.child("cars").addValueEventListener(*/ ... */);
```

And to get the `Car` object you can simply use:

```
Car car = childSnapshot.getValue(Car.class);
```

**Edit:** Seeing your entire database structure is more clear now. So to solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference carsRef = rootRef.child("cars");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Car car = ds.getValue(Car.class);
            Log.d(TAG, car.getHospital());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
carsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be: `11`.

Or in a more simpler way using the `Long` class:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference carsRef = rootRef.child("cars");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Long hospital = ds.child("hospital").getValue(Long.class);
            Log.d(TAG, hospital);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
carsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output will be the same.

There's also no need to use `@PropertyName` because all your fields in the class match the fileds in your database.

Comment: it is already assigned
mRoot = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("cars");
when i used this type of casting
Car car = childSnapshot.getValue(Car.class);
it said it cannot convert long to car

Comment: Please add a more detailed database structure, to see it more clearly.

Comment: you can give a look here
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/17xYkrFwZqscCdrzvfkStr6cC-VYaQHI1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It's not helping, that's why I've asked you to add a more detailed one.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SsJ83Pcw20pUMY0JdMMQrTG7W1Oo2tq2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Got it. Please see my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: greate it worked, but what was the reason why it didn't work first